# cakePHP email is not using my template to send email

Tags: email, cakephp

When sending email it has the standard message below in the footer.

This email was sent using the CakePHP Framework, http://cakephp.org.

It seems to use this one: `/lib/Cake/Console/Templates/skel/View/Layouts/Emails/text`

In my controller I have this.

```
$this->Email->sendAs = 'text';
$this->Email->template = 'dream';
```

Created the Views:

- /app/View/Emails/text/dream.ctp
- /app/View/Layouts/Emails/text/dream.ctp

Is there any other setting I miss to have cakephp using my layout?

*Note: if I rename my dream.ctp to default.ctp it uses that one, so it seems to ignore my template command? How odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### CakeEmail doesn't have a template property

Based on the paths shown in the question, you're using Cakephp 2. The [Cake Email](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-CakeEmail.html) class does not have a template property - which is why manipulating it has no effect.

### Refer to the documentation

The [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#sending-templated-emails) includes examples of usage, e.g.:

```
$Email = new CakeEmail();
$Email->template('dream', 'dreamy')
    ->emailFormat('text')
    ->to('bob@example.com')
    ->from('app@domain.com')
    ->send();
```

This will send the `dream` email using the `dreamy` layout.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I understand v2 uses CakeEmail, do I only need to modify my controller to make use of the CakeEmail? I don't fancy to redo my contact form, it has many fields and some checkboxes.